# Layered navigation is working in magento 2.1.7 but not working in magento 2.2.2

Tags: layered-navigation, magento2.2.2

Hear is my layout file same code is working fine in `magento 2.1.7` but not working in `magento 2.2.2`. I don't know why it's not working :

```
    <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\Category" name="catalog.leftnav" before="-" template="Demo_Shopby::layer/view.phtml">
            <block class="Demo\Shopby\Block\Navigation\State" name="catalog.navigation.state" as="state" />
            <block class="Magento\LayeredNavigation\Block\Navigation\FilterRenderer" name="catalog.navigation.renderer" as="renderer" template="layer/filter.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```